# I can no longer change my profile picture

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, profile-picture

Recently, I changed my profile picture when the *hats* feature was introduced. Since the hats have been disabled, my change profile picture link is no longer working.

Comment: I can reproduce this, and I did not change my picture during the hats season. Looks like a global problem.

Comment: how far does it get? does it list options? or...? (/cc @FrédéricHamidi)

Comment: @Marc, the "change picture" overlay is not shown on hover, and clicking on the avatar only reloads the profile page. There are no errors in the console. The problem occurs in all sites I tested, including beta sites.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hmmm; that's odd; seems to work here... http://i.stack.imgur.com/GpDOw.png; looking

Comment: @Marc, indeed it looks like it works for you :) I double-checked the HTTP traffic for blocked scripts and that stuff, everything looks fine on my end. The bug may only affect a subset of users (or your diamond is protecting you ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ah, I'm on the edit page; are you talking about the edit page? or the view page?

Comment: @Marc, ah, the view page, sorry. If memory serves, there was a "change picture" overlay that appeared when hovering over the avatar and allowed changing the picture without going to the edit page. Maybe this feature was retracted?

Comment: @marc, I was referring to the same edit page posted by you in the comments. Although, it's working fine now (it was not working until I posted this question).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is intentional, but is not related to "hats". We now support applying changes to individual sites or to the entire network, via the "Save changes just for this community" vs "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities". It was decided that with this feature, it is clearer if all changes (including profile images) go via this same screen.

The short answer here is: click "edit" and change it there.

Comment: "Save changes just for this community" is a terrible name for a button.  No one but the programmer who implemented it can be sure whether "this community" means "StackExchange technology sites", "StackOverflow", "StackOverflow and its associated meta", etc.  It should be spelled out.

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess spelling out the name of the site would make it easier to understand (although it seems clear enough to me). E.g. "save only for SO" or "save only for Physics.SE" and so on?

Comment: Editing one's profile should not be this complicated. I have to search for this every time I want to edit my profile. Simple is always better IMHO.

Comment: This way of changing the profile picture is just horrible complicated. I seriously had google "How to changed my profile picture", just to find out that I have to confirm it at the end of the page. Why double confirm?

Comment: There is nothing I can do after clicking edit. Literally no option to change my picture. Seriously ridiculous